# Make Jenkins visible to remote users

Tags: macos, jenkins

I have a Jenkins on my remote `MAC` machine and getting access through VNC. On remote machine I start jenkins via terminal like that: `brew services restart jenkins` and use it in local browser `localhost:8080`. But I need using jenkins from remote devices too. I've tried to open web form using IP address : `http://192.168.0000:8080` but always obtain `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. Firewall on Mac disabled. ping is 100%. I know `homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist` should contains string like that

`<string>--httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0</string>`

I've edited all these files and set `httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0`:

```
/Users/admin/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist
/usr/local/Cellar/jenkins/2.xxx/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist
/usr/local/opt/jenkins/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist
```

I have been even trying launch jenkins through terminal with parameters:

`jenkins.war -httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0 --httpPort=8080`

Nothing helped me. Remote browser still not sees my jenkins.

[image]

Comment: `192.168.0000` is not the correct address for your Mac server; are you actually using that address, or the correct address? Also, when trying to use it from remote devices, are you talking about devices that aren't on the same private network as the Mac? Because if you are, you need to access it via the public address of the router, and set up a port forward on the router, and maybe also worry about server-unfriendly things your ISP is doing like additional firewalling, carrier-grade NAT, etc.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I wrote `192.168.0000` just for example. Actually I always use one ip for connecting via VNC and when I attempt using jenkins in browser.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Mac and remote device both are in one private network.

Comment: Strange. Wrong IP would explain a timeout, but if the service wasn't listening on port 8080, I'd expect to get a rejected connection instead. Try running `netstat -an | grep 8080` on the server computer and make sure you see the "LISTEN" state. After that, I think I'd try running `tcpdump` (or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org)) on both computers, filtering for port 8080 and see what you get.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I'm sure 8080 port has `LISTEN` state. See screenshot above.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I tried the command on Mac machine `tcpdump port 8080` as result got `0 packets captured`.  ¯ \_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @GordonDavisson I also tried `>ssh -L 8080:IP:8080 username@IP` and that is 100% helped.

Comment: On macOS, `tcpdump` sometimes defaults to silly interfaces to listen on; try specifying it with e.g. `sudo tcpdump -ien0 port 8080` (assuming en0 is the relevant interface). If that still doesn't see any packets, I'm pretty sure you've got a rogue firewall in there somewhere.

Comment: @GordonDavisson unfortunately `sudo tcpdump -ien0 port 8080` also returned `0 packets captured`

Answer (score 4):

In 2021 on an M1 mac running BigSur the **Homebrew** plist file is actually located at `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jenkins/2.290/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist`

you will need to:
`sudo YOUR_FAV_EDITOR /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jenkins/2.290/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist`

and change the `--httpListenAddress` as noted above for all interfaces (0.0.0.0) to use `brew services start jenkins` / `brew services stop jenkins` / `brew services restart jenkins`

Hopefully, this updated information helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

In September 2022 in my case for jenkins-lts the file is located at `/usr/local/Cellar/jenkins-lts/2.361.1/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist`

Answer (score 0):

As a temp solution, may use SSH tunnel

> ssh -L 8080:IP:8080 username@IP